# JavaFX ListView SelectionModel java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: list, listview, javafx

I have written a JavaFX sample that shows a `ListView` (right) whose items are the selected items of another `ListView` (left). The right `ListView` automatically tracks the selection changes of the first one.

This works well, but there is an exception when I extend the selection beyond the lower end of the list using the keyboard: Selecting the last item of the list and then Shift+ArrowDown leads to this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Change state: next() must be
>   called before inspecting the Change.

Any idea why this happens? Is this a bug in my code or in JavaFX?

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items);

    MultipleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    ObservableList<String> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();

    ListView<String> selectedItemsListView = new ListView<>(selectedItems);

    HBox root = new HBox(5, listView, selectedItemsListView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
    stage.setTitle("List View Sample");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that... What JDK version and platform are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.2, jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: Weirdly, that's exactly the same setup I have. I tried again and still can't reproduce the issue. Maybe verify you aren't accidentally mixing and matching different versions of JavaFX (e.g. if you still have jfxrt.jar from JavaFX 2.2 on your classpath, or something).

Comment: No. Strange. The NetBeans project references `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`

Comment: Reproducible with 8.0.0-b132 but not 2.2.45-b18 on Windows..

Comment: I think it does not effect the app, so can be safely ignored until be fixed.